# Что такое "зависимости" и какие проблемы могут быть связаны с ними?

Tags: python, терминология

Может кто-то объяснить понятным языком, что такое "зависимости" и какие проблемы могут быть связаны с ними?

Я так понимаю, это наличие каких-то определённых установленных библиотек в системе, чтобы запустилось приложение.

У меня случилась небольшая проблема. Мне нужно посмотреть один opensource проект (Python, wxPython). Я сделал checkout его из репозитория, но там выдаётся ошибка при запуске. Я думаю, это как раз связано с зависимостями какими-то. В каком направлении мне действовать в решинии данной проблемы?

Comment: Ошибку то опишите, что на экране видите ?

Comment: ошибку я привел просто как пример возможной на мой вгляд проблемы с зависимостями.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Beremiz.py", line 148, in <module>
    from plugger import PluginsRoot, MATIEC_ERROR_MODEL
  File "/home/igor/proj/beremiz/plugger.py", line 16, in <module>
    from docpdf import *
ImportError: No module named docpdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Зависимости" это то что должно быть установлено перед тем как вы хотите что либо поставить. Как Вам уже сказали Вам не хватает "docpdf", я бы советовал бы сначала прочитать README(я не стебусь, чаще всего там есть раздел INSTALL, в котором описан подробный процесс установки и возможные проблемы)

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос конечно не особо информативен. Я так полагаю, что для запуска проекта необходимы сторонние библиотеке, которых вместе с исходниками не оказалось. Их нужно найти, скачать, и прицепить к проекту. Удачи.

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote
> ImportError: No module named docpdf

Собственно, здесь все и видно наглядно. Питон такой язык, в котором очень много различных модулей, как стандартных, так и дополняемых. Для работы этого проекта не хватает собственно модуля 'docpdf'. Найдите, скачайте и засуньте в папку /Lib

Comment: я вообще нигде не могу найти эту библиотеки (модуль), где посоветуйте поискать?

Comment: начал гуглить и наткнулся на ваш же пост на другом форуме :) вам там уже успели помочь, извините...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запустить окружение (если оно есть) и выполнить команду pip install pdf2odt

Comment: А какое отношение ваш ответ имеет к вопросу в этом топике, поясните пожалуйста?

Comment: Из дополнения к вопросу: "ошибку я привел просто как пример возможной на мой вгляд проблемы с зависимостями. Traceback (most recent call last): File "Beremiz.py", line 148, in <module> from plugger import PluginsRoot, MATIEC_ERROR_MODEL File "/home/igor/proj/beremiz/plugger.py", line 16, in <module> from docpdf import * ImportError: No module named docpdf "